# how to keep <br/> tags when using Dom in php to parse html document?

Tags: php, dom

i use dom in php to retrieve a div's content by `$node->nodeValue`. This div has many `<br/>` tags in its content, but after i store it in the database and output it in the browser, all the `<br/>` tags are changed to the whitespace. I want to keep the `<br/>` tags, how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMNode::nodeValue` will only return the text content.

As `<br />` is a child element, it won't be returned.

Your best bet is to

1. Create an empty, temporary string
2. Loop over all the child nodes in your `$node`
3. Get the markup of each child node using `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`
4. Concatenate this string with your temp one
5. Save the temp string to the database

Something like this - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718

Comment: Hi, I think [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#101243) is better since it uses the ownerDocument property(DOMDocument object defined for every DOMNode, DOMElement object) and avoid creating more DOMDocument objects that we need for this.

Answer (score 9):

nodeValue returns only the text-data (if used on element-nodes). Retrieve the contents using [saveXML()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savexml.php)

```
$node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
```

Comment: That will also output the containing `<div>` represented by `$node`

Comment: Shouldn't be so hard to remove those tags from the resulting string if needed :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using MySQL (since you don't say) make sure you use the function `mysql_real_escape_string`.  Dr.Molle's answer might provide further insight.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php