# nodeValue when working with PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I'm working on a parser to output specific elements of a PHP DOM, such as heading tags, images etc in a HTML page (I have no control over the page) and I'd like to get the nodeValue/textContent of the DOM node without concatenation that doesn't preserve effective whitespace (read: newlines) in visual HTML.

For example, the current code to export Heading Tags is as follows, nice and simple:

```
function getHeadingTags($content){
    $this->dom = new DomDocument();
    @$this->dom->loadHTML($contents);

    $this->xpath = new DOMXPath($this->dom);
    $this->xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
    $this->xpath->registerPHPFunctions();

    $nodes = $this->xpath->query('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5|//h6');

    $results = array();

    if ($nodes->length > 0)
    {       
        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {                   
            $results[$node->tagName][] = trim($node->textContent);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This is working absolutely fine for standard strings, however if you have HTML such as:

```
<h1>This is a heading<br>that spans two lines</h1>
```

Results in a nasty concatenated string:

```
This is a headingthat spans two lines
```

One could, of course, preg_replace the `<br>` elements et al but it just feels a little hacky. I've handled a hierarchy of elements through the use of recursion with `$node->childNodes` and a foreach loop I just wondered if there was a solution that doesn't require what I feel to be pretty hacky find and replace work on the remaining top-level DOM elements.

I presume this would be a problem with lists as well, take for example the following code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

I presume a nodeValue on the `<ul>` would output similar to `TestTest2` rather than the hoped for `Test Test2` I know this is expected behaviour but I was hoping for a decent work around if anyone has one to hand?

Comment: Just to note, the recursion through the child nodes handles the second example (ul list) but completely escapes the inline `<br>`.

Comment: This might be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864582/how-to-keep-br-tags-when-using-dom-in-php-to-parse-html-document)

Comment: Or you should checkout [this answer](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php5-need-something-like-innerhtml-instead-of-nodevalue/4971/9).

Comment: I'm not wanting to keep any tags, I'm wanting to remove them but them be replaced with a space rather than concatenated. The examples you've shown are all about identifying the DOM of HTML of the lower nodes, which whilst useful is the hacky approach I mention in my question - I'm after an approach that doesn't involve find and replace, preg_replace etc it seems simple but actually a difficult question to address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recursively search into children of the node for DOMText node and join them with a whitespace:

```
function getNodeText(DOMNode $node) {
    if (is_a($node, "DOMText"))
        return trim($node->nodeValue);

    $nodeValues = array();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    {
        $nodeText = getNodeText($child);
        if ($nodeText != "")
        {
            $nodeValues[] = $nodeText;
        }
    }
    return trim(implode(" ", $nodeValues));
}

function getHeadingTags($content) {
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
    $xpath->registerPHPFunctions();

    $nodes = $xpath->query('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5|//h6');

    $results = array();

    if ($nodes->length > 0)
    {       
        foreach ($nodes as $node)
        {                   
            $results[$node->tagName][] = getNodeText($node);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

See an example here: https://3v4l.org/pYMFr

Comment: @williamvicary, you are welcome! If the answer is good for you, you can also accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to separate the values and the output logically (in your mind).

1. Assumed someone has 100 </br>-Tags perhaps you don't want to render that, and it shows very clear what you wrote already with your short example.
2. Another option is to print the html-tags or only the content (between the tags).
3. One proposition is to replace some nodes by special signs (i.e. br-tag by \n and tab bei \t).
4. If you know a bit about online-editors (like here on stackoverflow where you inserted your question) you know perhaps that paragraph-tags are just added in the frontend but the texts often are saved without the p-tags in the database.
5. Point 4. leads to this point: when you save the data in the database you've to parse them perhaps different than if you just print the output.
6. If you want keep some logic of the tags like h1-h6 or lists which imply some line-breaks too perhaps you want to parse to another existing structure-format. You could use "markdown" [1] or "ReStructuredText" [2].

Depending on the time you've for the issue you can either use something like "markdown" to replace HTML-Tags or you just replace a few things like line-breaks like you want. I wrote some parsers and often saved the original HTML still in a database field, so I always could control the nodes I saved in separated fields.

Concerning lists you just could replace </li> by </br>.
If you never know the pages you parse you've to assume perhaps that many other tags still are included, i.e. dl, dt, dd, address, ....

And even you verify all HTML-tags by the standard you've no guaranty that they are used like this. An example are menus built with ul-lists, where the display on the page is often much different after styling by CSS, so many attributes of elements can be changed and you can't rely on the original attributes of block-elements or inline-elements.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comment. I'm working with data from the web and then running checks against that data. So for example, I might crawl a website and identify the number of times a phrase is used but if words are concatenated (as is the case from PHP DOM) then these checks may fail where they should pass (this test is an example but there are many purposes for this such as identifying n-grams etc).

Comment: Hi @William In that case you just can add white spaces after each expression.
Even if the things are shown on the page several white spaces are shown in HTML only as one.